# can't emit a signal from a class called by a thread in QT

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, signals-slots

I've made a thread that initiates a class and runs some methods of that class. the class was originally made in VS console app and then I transferred my project into QT.

**VERY SORRY FOR THIS LONG POST**

//mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

#include "serverstart.h"

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

signals:

public slots:
    void serverStartedSlt();

public:
    QThread *mythread;
    ServerStart *serverstart;
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

//mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

//for server start thread
#include <QThread>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::serverStartedSlt(){
    ui->pushButton->setText("Stop Server");
    ui->pushButton->setStyleSheet("background:red;");
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    serverstart = new ServerStart();
    mythread = new QThread(this);
    serverstart->moveToThread(mythread);
    QObject::connect(mythread, &QThread::started, serverstart, &ServerStart::run);
    //this is what would connect mysignal from server.cpp with mainwindow.cpp to edit in the UI
    QObject::connect(serverstart, &ServerStart::serverStartedSig, this, &MainWindow::serverStartedSlt);
    mythread->start();
}
```

here is what i run in my thread.

//serverstart.h

```
#ifndef SERVERSTART_H
#define SERVERSTART_H

#include <QDebug>

class ServerStart : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

signals:
    //adding signal again in serverstart.h
    void serverStartedSig();

public:
    explicit ServerStart(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~ServerStart();

public slots:
    void run();

};

#endif // SERVERSTART_H
```

//serverstart.cpp

```
#include "server.h" //my server class
#include "serverstart.h"

ServerStart::ServerStart(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

ServerStart::~ServerStart(){

}

void ServerStart::run()
{
    qInfo() << "\nthread is running\n";

    Server MyServer(4040, true);
    MyServer.ListenForNewConnection();

    MyServer.HandleInput(); //while(true) loop

    qInfo() << "\nthread stoped\n";
    this->deleteLater();
}
```

here is the class I included in my thread class.
it was made in VS console app, then I copied it as is.
//server.h

```
#pragma once
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
//a lot of headers

//for definig signals
#include <QDebug>

//simple connection class
class Connection
{

};

//the server class used and i want to emit the signal from it
class Server : public QObject //derivnig from QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT //adding the macros

signals:
    //defining the signal
    void serverStartedSig();

public:
    //these what i use in my thread class
    Server(int PORT, bool BroadcastPublically = false);
    
    void ListenForNewConnection();
    void HandleInput();
    static Server * serverptr;

private:
   //a lot of methods
};
```

//server.cpp

```
#include "server.h"
//other headers

Server* Server::serverptr;

Server::Server(int PORT, bool BroadcastPublically)
{
    //emitting the signal
    emit serverStartedSig();
    //init winsock
    //bind, listen
    
    //low level thread.
    _beginthreadex(NULL, NULL, (_beginthreadex_proc_type)PacketSenderThread, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}
```

when i create a new server class and use it instead of this one, it throws an error in server.obj, i guess its because of the constructor that was created in VS console app. `Server(int PORT, bool BroadcastPublically)`

Comment: This won't compile. Your ServerStart class doesn't have a signal called `serverStartedSig`, but you are trying to connect it to something.

Comment: And why threads at all - just because it's cool? There is absolutely no need for two threads here...

Comment: even when i add  `signals: void serverStartedSig();` it doesn't work, i think the server class  needs to be derived from QObject class.

i absoluteley need threads in my program, that's a packet sender thread that looks fro packets that need to be sent and send them one by one. i want to be able to do things with the serverstart  thread which is in a `while` loop while the packet sender thread is sending the packets.

Comment: i've added everything but nothing happends

Comment: i've wached a youtuber talking about emiting the signal twice in some cases. do i need to do that also.

emitting the signal from server.cpp to serverstart.cpp then emmiting it again from serverstart.cpp to mainwindow.cpp

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  You connect to the `ServerStart::serverStartedSig` signal but never emit that signal.  You *do* emit the `Server::serverStartedSig` signal but only from the `Server` constructor so it's emitted before anything can be connected to it.  You need to take a step back and do some basic debugging.  If you're not sure whether a signal is being emitted or not try connecting it to a simple lambda that generates some logging output -- it'll help you home in on the real issue.

Comment: ok, i finally solved the problem by emitting the signal twice.

Comment: @G.M. you're right, i'm now calling it from a  method in the Server.cpp. then connecting it to a slot in serverstart.cpp then emitting another signal from the lot and connecting it in mainwindow.h. this is the only solution i think.

Comment: my question is... is there any perfomance issues when emitting signals using a chain of signals and slots like this. i'm very new to signals and slots